# Select an id within another id with CSS & php query parameter

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress I have a template that changes certain elements based on a query parameter

e.g. www.mysite.com/member-levels/?level=3

The template creates a div on the page with an id related to this query param.

e.g `<div id="mem_level-<?php echo $mem_level->id; ?>">`

Within the mem-level div is another div with an id so it looks like this

```
<div id="mem_level-X">
   <div id="mem_message">
```

What I am trying to achieve is to change the mem_message styles differently depending on the mem-level. (It will be different colours etc for membership levels e.g. Bronze, Silver, Gold)

How can I select the different mem_message div's with css so I can style them individually. If it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a descendant or direct child [CSS Combinator](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

```css
#mem_message {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
}

#mem_level-1 > #mem_message {
 background-color: #ffbc00;
}

#mem_level-2 > #mem_message {
 background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

#mem_level-3 > #mem_message {
 background-color: #c78027;
}
```

```html
<div id="mem_level-1">
   <div id="mem_message">
      Level1
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="mem_level-2">
   <div id="mem_message">
   Level2
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="mem_level-3">
   <div id="mem_message">
   Level3
   </div>
</div>
```

I recommend that you use [classes instead of IDs](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) if there's going to be more than one `mem_message` / `mem_level-x` on the same page.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you this is what I needed!

Comment: Also props for the Code demo. Maybe other answers also work but seeing it work is always helpful.

Comment: @PaulLeppard No, that's not what you needed. This is an invalid HTML code. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Really...? Ok I hadn't checked it out yet.

Comment: @RacilHilan You are right that's it's not valid if #mem_message is present more than once in the webpage. That's why I added a link explaining when to use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: @PaulLeppard It's invalid for demo purposes. It's valid if `#mem_message` is only present once on the generated webpage received by the client. If not, you should use `class="<class-name>"` instead of `id="<class-name>"` and replace the `#` with `.` in the CSS.

Comment: #mem-message only appears once but it is within #mem_level-x so will it work in this case? The page will need to reload if the query string in changed..

Comment: @PaulLeppard yes.

Comment: @PaulLeppard Your comments are not clear. You said the `X` will be a number that changes. Will all of them be on one page? In this case the HTML will be invalid because you will have several boxes with ID `mem_message`. If only one `mem_level-X` will be on the page each time, then you don't need this answer and all you need is `#mem_message` like in the second example of my answer. But if you want to process `mem_message` differently each time, then you can use this answer, or the last example of my answer.

Comment: OK let me explain. The Wordpress plugin is Paid Memberships Pro. In a Worpress Page I place a shortcode for a registration form. The page never changes only the query-parameter. So Bronze is 1, Silver is 2, Gold is 3. The template sends the html to the browser with the different Div id mem_level-1. If I only use #mem_message to style then the styles will be the same regardless of what the Query Parameter is. Which is what I don't want. If I have 3 different css rules set up only the one with the correct query-parameter will fire and thus should be correct. I haven't had a chance to try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the inner `div` in CSS like this:

```
#mem_level-X > #mem_message
```

Here is a demo:

```css
#mem_level-X > #mem_message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mem_level-X">
  Outer div
  <div id="mem_message">Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
```

However, this is pointless for IDs because they're unique, so it is more efficient to just use the ID of the inner `div` alone:

```css
#mem_message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mem_level-X">
  Outer div
  <div id="mem_message">Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
```

**Edit** based on your comment, you will have several boxes and you're changing the ID of the outer box, so that's good. You'll have to do the same for the inner box and change it's ID because IDs must be unique, in which case my comment above is still valid and there is no point in selecting an ID inside another ID, just select the inner ID directly. Alternatively, you can use a class instead of an ID on the inner box and then select them like this:

```
#mem_level-X > .mem_message
```

Here is a demo:

```css
#mem_level-1 > .mem_message {
  color: red;
}

#mem_level-2 > .mem_message {
  color: blue;
}

#mem_level-3 > .mem_message {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="mem_level-1">
  Outer div
  <div class="mem_message">Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
<div id="mem_level-2">
  Outer div
  <div class="mem_message">Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
<div id="mem_level-3">
  Outer div
  <div class="mem_message">Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
```

Or you can simply use nothing (neither ID nor class) and select them like this:

```
#mem_level-X > div
```

Here is a demo:

```css
#mem_level-1 > div {
  color: red;
}

#mem_level-2 > div {
  color: blue;
}

#mem_level-3 > div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="mem_level-1">
  Outer div
  <div>Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
<div id="mem_level-2">
  Outer div
  <div>Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
<div id="mem_level-3">
  Outer div
  <div>Inner div</div>
  Outer div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the point is the 'X' changes based on the query parameter so the top div can either be mem_level-1 or  mem_level-2 or  mem_level-3 etc

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can only have one element with ID `mem_message` on your page. If you make it a class instead of and ID, that will work and you can use `#mem_level-X > .mem_message`. Alternatively, you need neither a class nor and ID, you can simply use `#mem_level-X > div` if the outer `div` contains no other `div`s. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood, but can't you use;

```
#mem_level-X #mem_message{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

If you have more than one of these on a page, then you may be better to use;

```
class="mem_message-X" & class="mem_message"
```

instead with;

```
.mem_level-X .mem_message{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its simple : use selector :

```
#mem_level-X #mem_message{ style  }
as value of x will change according to the url parameter  so you can easily change color scheme according to the level..

#mem_level-1 #mem_message{ border:1px solid #000;background:#555; }
#mem_level-2 #mem_message{ border:1px solid #000;background:red; }
etc....
```